# Opening a SWF file in VLC Player?

Tags: flash

I was browsing a really old site that had tutorial videos using Adobe Flash Player. I tried opening the site in way back machine, which runs Ruffle. That didn't seem to work.

So, I downloaded the swf file by grabbing the href link and opened the file via VLC Player.

This was probably a really dumb thing to do.....what are the chances I have infected my computer with a virus? Are there any recommendations to undo this mistake? I have permanently deleted the swf file as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with flash are not the SWF files themselves - its vulnerabilities in the Flash player which were exploited with using specifically prepared SWF files designed to exploit these vulnerabilities.

So, if you take an SWF file which is likely not containing an exploit in the first place, then opening it in an application which is not the vulnerable Flash player - then the chances of compromising your system this way are very low. It would require that the downloaded files exploit a vulnerability in VLC, not in the original Flash player.